# adding a right click event for nav menu in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am working in an angular app,
navigation part which need right click unable and open as new tab tooltip when I try to add routerLink it becomes 404 error. could anyone help me to add right click event for this , my code is as below

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let gotolink of allLInks">
                            <a
                              class="nav"
                              (click)="onClicktonav(gotolink?.path, gotolink.name)"    
 [routerLink]="['/gotolink?.path']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"                        >
                                                            <span class="Header-user-link-text">
                                {{ gotolink.name }}
                              </span>
                            </a>
                          </ng-container>
```

above my html

```
onClicktonav(path, name) {
    if (name === 'about') {
      this.gtmService.pushGTMTags('aboutpage', {
        fromPage: 'rightsidebar',
      });
    } else if (title === 'services') {
    } else if (title === 'contact') {
    } else if (title === 'blog') {
      this.gtmService.pushGTMTags('blogpage');
    }
    this.router.navigate([path]);
  }
```

now the links working right click is throwing 404 error I want to make right click also work for this

[routerLink]="['/gotolink?.path']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
I added this inside html and was expecting right click work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable right-click functionality on your Angular app without causing a 404 error, you need to handle the right-click event separately. You can use a custom right-click event in Angular by using the (contextmenu) event. Here's how you can make it work:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let gotolink of allLInks">
  <a class="nav" (click)="onClicktonav(gotolink?.path, gotolink.name)" (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event, gotolink?.path)">
    <span class="Header-user-link-text">
      {{ gotolink.name }}
    </span>
  </a>
</ng-container>
```

and ts :

```
onRightClick(event: MouseEvent, path: string) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default context menu from showing up
  // Your custom code for handling the right-click event
  window.open(path, '_blank'); // Open the link in a new tab
}
```